# Analytic branch of $\sqrt{1-z^2}$ on a region $U$ where $\pm 1$ are is the same connected component of $U^c$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis

I'm struggling to verify one part of this problem.  The essential idea is that since $\pm 1$ live in the same connected component of $U^c$, given any piecewise smooth closed curve $\gamma$ into $U$, the winding number $\eta(\gamma,\cdot)$ is constant on said region containing $\pm 1$.

Now, ideally we want something like $e^{\frac{1}{2}\log(1-z^2)}$ defined on $U$, but the problem is that $U$ can easily be such that there does not exist any analytic branch of $\log$ defined on all of $U$.  However, if we niavely differentiate $\log(1-z^2)$, we yield $\frac{-2z}{1-z^2}$.  Hence, given a fixed $z_0 \in U$, I want to define a map $F:U \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by: $$F(z) = \text{exp}\left(\frac{1}{2}\int_{\gamma} \frac{-2w}{1-w^2}  dw \right)$$ where $\gamma$ is any piecewise smooth curve from $z_0$ to $z$.  This is well defined since if $\sigma$ is a piecewise smooth closed curve in $U$, then: $$\int_{\sigma} \frac{-2w}{1-w^2}  dw = 4 \pi i \eta(\sigma,1) \in 4 \pi i \mathbb{Z}$$ by performing a PFD, and using that $\eta(\sigma,1) = \eta(\sigma,-1)$.  Thus, exponentiating by $e^{\frac{1}{2}z}$ gives you: $$\text{exp}\left(\frac{1}{2}\int_{\sigma} \frac{-2w}{1-w^2} dw \right)=1.$$  Moreover, it's clear to me that $F$ is continuous.  The issue I'm having is I don't see how $F$ could be analytic.

In order to verify analycity, I would need to prove that the map $G(z) = \int_{\gamma} \frac{-2w}{1-w^2} dw$ is analytic on $U$ (so $G$ is the inside part of the exponential defining $F$).  The only thing I could think of doing is applying Fubini-Tonelli to $\frac{-2w}{1-w^2}$. in an attempt to prove $G$ is path independent and then apply Morera's theorem.  So, if $\sigma$ is a piecewise smooth closed curve in $U$, and $\gamma: [0,1] \longrightarrow U$ by $\gamma(t) = z_0+t(z-z_0)$ then by Fubini-Tonelli: $$\int_{\sigma} G(z) dz = \int_{\sigma} \left(\int_{0}^1 \frac{-2(z_0+t(z-z_0))(z-z_0)}{1-(z_0+t(z-z_0))^2}  dt\right) dz$$ $$= \int_{0}^1 \left(\int_{\sigma} \frac{-2(z_0+t(z-z_0))(z-z_0)}{1-(z_0+t(z-z_0))^2} dz \right)dt.$$  However, there isn't any obvious reason that I see why this double integral is $0$.

I would be really appreciative if someone could give me a *hint* on how to solve this.   Thank you.

Comment: This question could use some clarification of the hypotheses as well as the
author's background and source of the problem. What's true is that if $U$ an
open connected subset of $\mathbb{C}$ such that $U^{\complement}$ is closed,
bounded, connected, and contains $1$ and $-1$, then there exists a unique holomorphic map $f:U\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z)^2=1-z^2$ and$\lim_{z\to\infty}\tfrac{f(z)}{z}=\mathrm{i}$. (Ultimately, because the map from the conic $w^2=1-z^2$ to the line that forgets $w$ is a branched degree-two cover.)